# No suitable driver found for jdbc error in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I'm developing a dynamic web application through eclipse IDE and using Tomcat 7.0 to deploy the war file. I'm trying to connect to database through a method by passing url, username and password parameters in the `getConnection()`.

I have placed the `db2jcc` jars in the tomcat lib folder. I'm getting the sql exception as

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:DB2://localhost:50000/InstanceName
```

in the eclipse server console. Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

```
protected Statement dynamiCreateDBStatement(String url, String DB_Uname,String DBPWD,String DB_Type) 
{
    try {
        System.out.println(url+"uname="+DB_Uname+"pwd="+DBPWD);
        if(DB_Type.equals("") || DB_Type.equals("null") == false)
        {
            if(DB_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("DB2"))
            {
                Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            }
            if(DB_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("oracle"))
            {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            }
        }
        String type="javax.sql.DataSource";

        connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DB_Uname, DBPWD);
        stmt1 = connection1.createStatement();
        connection1.close();
        System.out.println("close conn to db=="+connection1.isClosed());
        return stmt1;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("sql ="+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("class=="+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to try `jdbc:db2` instead of `jdbc:DB2`

Comment: Note that this has almost nothing to do with Tomcat: no Tomcat code is involved with this particular problem. In general, it is probably preferable to use Tomcat to configure a DBCP pool to manage your resources more safely.

Comment: thanks a lot Mark and Christopher for valuable information. The problem was with the DBtype as mentioned by Mark. Lowercase db2 worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"No suitable driver" usually means that the JDBC URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax or when the driver isn't loaded at all.

Check the URL syntax. That error usually means that the driver class was loaded, but the URL was incorrect. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0512kokkat/#connect) are the docs to show you what the correct syntax is.

When the method getConnection is called, the `DriverManager` will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.(using `Class.forName()`)

This may also happen if `db2cc.jar` is not in your classpath.I would suggest to place `db2cc.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.Then eclipse will take care for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

since the DB2 driver is considered as an external jar file to your IDE tool, you need to add it to it.
In Eclipse you need to go to menu Run -> Run Configurations and in the tab Classpath add the external DB2 jar file.
This way your java class has access to it.

Good luck, Boris

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this error by fixing the connection URL. By mistake it was:
*jdbc:postgresql:/192.168.141.113:5432/* with only one slash before the IP.
Adding the double slash: *jdbc:postgresql://192.168.141.113:5432/* fixed this error